# Is there a benefit to separating these 2 structures of data?

Tags: database-design

In a recruiting application I'm building, a part of it involves a user resource. Afterwards, they all fill in a "common application". Essentially this is not linked to any particular job, it's akin to them filling out a general profile.

With this, I could have a

User model
has_one: Common_app

But, I could have just a User model, and have the common app info inside the user model.

I'm a bit of a noob, so I might be missing something. Is there an advantage to choosing to separate the structures or not?

Comment: Depends on things like if it'll always stay 1-to-1 or if you envision 1-to-Many in future, if the resource/common_app is strictly structured already or if it can evolve to be more complicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With 1-to-1 relationships, it's tempting to just make your secondary table a simple extension of the first. But you'll want to ask yourself it it's truly 1-to-1, or just 1-to-1 "right now".

For example, if the user changes their common app, would you simply destroy their old one and replace it? Or would you deactivate it, mark the old one with an end date, and start up a new one?

Also, is there any possibility that in the future, they may have multiple?

If you have any doubts, I'd definitely consider it a 1-to-many, even if at the moment you're only expecting it to be 1-to-1. It gives you the wiggle room down the road if you ever need it, without having to redesign your data structure.

That's something to keep in mind with a lot of your decisions. Are you "absolutely 100% positive" that today's rules will always be in place? If not, then either build an escape into your original design, or recognize that changes down the road may require considerable work.